How to perform OpenCV boxFilter for a ROI?
I have an image and I want to perform OpenCV boxFilter on a ROI of this image.
image = cv::imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   
cv::Rect roi( 10, 10, 64, 64);
cv::Mat output;
cv::boxFilter(image(roi),output,-1,cv::Size(scale_size,scale_size));

I want to know what happen if the kernel is out of the ROI? Use the pixels out of the ROI but still within the image to do the filtering or just use the value specified by the BorderType?
Actually I want to use the former to do the filtering.

you want to know what happens? just write a little test program and see what happens. you don't need to occupy anyone's time to figure this out. -- if you don't like the border behavior of processing on just the ROI, the common solution is to filter the entire picture, then copy the region out of the filtered version.

@ChristophRackwitz this might be very inefficient if the original image is far bigger than the ROI one. Isn't it enough to enlarge the ROI a bit (by ~half the filter kernel size) ?

sure. in other situations (not this one) where someone would want to process a lot of little ROIs, the balance of the tradeoff tips in the other direction.

I'm pretty sure I read somewhere and tested myself, that when using a filter on a subimage, the original image pixels outside of the subimage are used for the border. Not sure about the specific box filter implementation though, afair I tested on Sobel filter.

@EnJ my original answer (that you accepeted) turned out to be wrong. See Micka's excellent answer for all the details. I think you should consider to accept it instead of mine. In any case I updated my answer to add some info why the actual behavior (of using pixels out of the ROI) is implied.

My original answer (got accepted) was that cv::boxFilter will not use the pixels out of the ROI.
This actually turned out to be wrong.
See @Micka's excellent answer that demonstrates that by default cv::boxFilter does use the pixels out of the ROI.
It is also discussed in this github issue.
I just wanted to add that although this behavior is not well documented, it is implied:
cv::boxFilter has a flag-like parameter borderType.
The values for it should come from enum cv::BorderTypes (some values can be combined by |).
The last value of the enum is:
BORDER_ISOLATED    = 16 //!< do not look outside of ROI

This implies that if this value is not used, the function will look outside of the ROI.

please review your first sentence.

@ChristophRackwitz can you explain your meaning ? I meant that pixels in image which are not in image(roi) are not relevant (because as I explained later the input for boxFilter is image(roi)).

missing verb ("which are in the..."). and then the wording (two negations) feels unwieldy. you mean to talk about "the pixels in the original image but not the ROI", which is equivalent to "the pixels outside of the ROI", which can only come from the rest of the original image (it is implied).

@ChristophRackwitz I see, rephrased now. Is it clear ?

looks good to me

see https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5263

I think the accepted answer is wrong.
In the past I tested it with Sobel filter and I'm pretty sure I also found the original documentation or a semi-official answer from opencv that filters in subimages use the real border pixels from the original image.
EDIT: Found it (not a bug but a feature):
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5263
I now tested this for box-filter with this code:
int main()
{
    try
    {
        cv::Mat image = cv::imread("Lenna.png");

        cv::Rect roi(10, 10, 64, 64);

        // box filter on roi which is a subimage of the full image
        cv::Mat output_roi;
        cv::boxFilter(image(roi), output_roi, -1, cv::Size(5, 5));

        // box filter on a deep copy of the roi/subimage region
        cv::Mat copy = image(roi).clone();
        cv::Mat output_copy;
        cv::boxFilter(copy, output_copy, -1, cv::Size(5, 5));

        // highlight the differences between both results
        cv::Mat diff;
        cv::absdiff(output_roi, output_copy, diff);

        cv::cvtColor(diff, diff, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        std::cout << "non-zero diff between clone and roi: " << cv::countNonZero(diff) << std::endl;

        // now compute on full image and extract roi result:
        cv::Mat output_full;
        cv::boxFilter(image, output_full, -1, cv::Size(5, 5));

        cv::Mat diff_full;
        cv::absdiff(output_roi, output_full(roi), diff_full);

        cv::cvtColor(diff_full, diff_full, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        std::cout << "non-zero diff between full(roi) and roi: " << cv::countNonZero(diff_full) << std::endl;


        cv::imshow("diff>0", diff > 0);
        cv::imshow("diff_full>0", diff_full > 0);
        cv::waitKey(0);
    }
    catch(cv::Exception &e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

Result is a diff between the clone and the roi but no diff between the the roi and the fullimage-result (in the roi region).
non-zero diff between clone and roi: 297
non-zero diff between full(roi) and roi: 0

here are the result images:
diff>0

diff_full>0

result images (hard to see the difference ;) ):
roi:

copy:

full:


Does the sub cv::Mat have a reference (in the general sense) to the whole image ? If so - can you explain which member holds this reference ? I think this is required if the filter implemenetation is accessing pixels out of the ROI.

is this behavior documented? I think that's something the docs should make a definite statement on. -- yes, mats sharing the same memory have a reference to that memory, which is an object in its own right. it has to be. it's doing reference counting. as such, any mat referencing that memory can know its "full" extent.
